# Get clean URL from firebase storage (without token)

Tags: node.js, firebase, shopify, firebase-storage

I'm developing a project where I need to send images url to Shopify admin API, the problem I'm having is that shopify doesn't recognize the URL as valid because of the trailing parameters

> image.jpg?alt=media&token=9dab5705-351c-44f2-81a6-fc1b4b6eaf56

My question is:

1. Is there a way to generate clean URL with firebase storage?
2. if not, is there a work around? like somehow create a proxy script `www.scripturl.com/fakeimageurl.jpg` and retrieve `firebasestorageurl.com/realimage.jpg?alt=media&token=9dab5705-351c-44f2-81a6-fc1b4b6eaf56` with it?

The project is with `nodejs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the images are public, you can use the public url, which will end with your file's extension

```
storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
[BUCKET_NAME].storage.googleapis.com/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

Firebase storage uses google cloud storage under the hood, and you can use any of the mechanisms available there, this documentation explains some [reference URIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-uris)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you, it was so simple that I feel ashamed.